# Can the possessive の particle be used like this? あの かさ は だれ の ですか

Tags: grammar, particle-の

I was reading about possession on the particle の and it stated one of the ways you can show possession was

> これ は だれ の かんばん ですか

and I was just wondering if this would also work

> あの かさ は だれ の ですか

I'm not sure if you need to have something for the の to connect to or if you can just do it this way.

Comment: The spacing would be a lot more normal as あのかさは　だれのですか？ and これは　だれの　かんばんですか？ (and it would be easier to read).

Comment: `かんばん` -- 「かばん」じゃなくて看板？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. This is one of the cases where `の` effectively acts as `の + noun`. The noun is implicit and as stated in previous answers it is 物{もの}. You can read more about how `の` works [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works. だれの can stand for だれのもの too.

Answer (score 0):

Well... how about this

> あの かさ は だれ の **もの** ですか
>   Ano kasa-wa dare-no **mono** desu-ka?